# converting object to array and two nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new in react, so i saw a burger project which really make me feel confused.

Well i have state of object:

```
state = {
   ingredients: {
      bacon: 1,
      cheese: 3,
      meat: 2,
      salad: 1
    }
  }
```

so i pass the state as props to the stateful component to make the burger dynamically

Here this is the nightmare :

```
const Burger = (props) => {
  const newIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients).map(ingredientsName => {
const quantity = props.ingredients[ingredientsName];

 return [...Array(quantity)]).map((_, i) => {
   
   return <BurgerIngredient key={ingredientsName + i} type={ingredientsName} /> 
    )
    })  
  })
```

1)would you please explain this block of code for me i am stocked .
2)why not using Object.enteries() instead of Object.keys().

Comment: I think you should be more specific. This is javascript sytax and if it's not clear to you then you should review it part with the help of the JS docs.

Comment: To understand `Object.keys`, `Object.entries` , `Object.values` and their usage, you can look at [this tutorial](https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries)